# Equivalent to Java Topology Suite and Jena TBD in Python

Tags: java, python, geometry, topology

I normally use the [Java Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) to handle 2D geometries in Java.

Is there a similar library in Python, supporting some spatial standard such as [GML](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards)?

Answer (score 3):

Shapely (https://github.com/sgillies/shapely) is based on GEOS, the C/C++ port of JTS. JTS implements OGC simple features, not GML. Shapely doesn't read/write GML either.